# Identify column using column header and delete rows where cell contains substring

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to produce some VBA code that will look for my column that contains the column header "New query" in the first cell for row 1. It should then delete all rows where the substring value '' is present in each cell for the column.

This is what I have come up with:

```
Set rng = Rows("1:1").Find(what:="New query", after:=Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
With Intersect(Sheets("Sheet1")
.Columns(rng.EntireColumn.Address))
.Replace "''", "#N/A", xlPart
.SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlErrors).EntireRow.Delete
End With
```

Comment: And? What happens? Is that two separate single quotes?

Comment: I get a compile syntax error on the line starting With Intersect... and yes they are two separate single quotes. It says argument not optional

Comment: You perhaps need `With Intersect(Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange, rng.EntireColumn)`. Might also have problems if your cells contain just two single quotes. Is this imported from elsewhere?

Comment: Hi, not imported from anywhere. I made the change and now get rng.EntireColumn = <Object variable or With block variable not set> error

Comment: You need to check that the value is found first. Have you stepped through your code? If you have a choice I would not use single apostrophes as they can be confused by the text prefix.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to use `Intersect` for this, and it's causing the problem.  Try this instead:

```
Set Rng = Rows("1:1").Find(what:="New query", after:=Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
With Rng.EntireColumn
    .Replace "''", "#N/A", xlPart
    .SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlErrors).EntireRow.Delete
End With
```